# Непонятен паттерн Filter в Java

Tags: java, шаблоны-проектирования, filter

Доброго времени суток, досталось мне задание, в котором нужно использовать паттерн Filter. Но гугл мне свет так и не пролил на то, как с ним работать конкретно в моём задании.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я себе эту задачу представил так:
Есть серверное приложение, к которому могут подключаться клиенты. После подключения клиент передает информацию о себе (IP, порт и т.д.), а сервер, с помощью вот этого паттерна из общего потока данных вычленяет инфу по каждой категории. Но как с этим паттерном работать я так и не понял. Буду очень признателен, если кто-то пояснит.

Comment: а может имелось в виду Intercepting filter?

Comment: Патерны -- зло.

Comment: @Qwertiy а можно чуть подробнее, почему? И почему их тогда спрашивают на собеседованиях к примеру?

Comment: @pavel, просто высказал мнение в комментарии. Если кратко, потому что их пытаются совать во все щели. А подробно расписывать лень...